# How to get required data from the string

Tags: python

I had string, for example

```
s = '\r\n<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> \r\n\r\n<p>\r\n\t\r\n\t\t<A HREF="../temp/Table 32012419252223.xls">Click to download</A>\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\t</P>'
```

I need to fetch only `/temp/Table 32012419252223.xls` from the above string.

Secondly, I had a link, for example

```
link = "www.example.com/flow/hardway/joshing/high"
```

Now I need to replace `"joshing/high"` from the above link with the result of first one (`/temp/Table 32012419252223.xls`).

Comment: Please clarify: for part 1, if I had a different example, how would I know what is to be extracted from it?  And for part 2, if I had a different example, how would I know what part of the link should be replaced?

Answer (score 2):

If you are parsing HTML or XML documents, use an approriate library. An example using lxml and xpath would be:

```
from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring
from urlparse import urljoin

s = 'yourhtml'
h = fromstring(s)
print urljoin(link, h.xpath('//a[1]/@href')[0]))
```

to get the first link on the page. You can also use more complex XPath expressions if the HTML is more complex.